# Octave demodmap function - simple assist

Tags: octave, fsk

I'm a beginner with Octave.  I'm trying to de-modulate a simple FSK file (wav file of alternating 2KHz and 4KHz tones at 500 bits per second, into an array of 1s and 0s. I read the documentation for function demodmap in the communications package, but I must be understanding something wrong. I need a simple example that works.

[image]

```
data = audioread("monoshort8008n9.wav");
z = demodmap( data, 500, 44100, "fsk", 2);
```

Two errors occur. First 44100 is not a multiple of 500 as required by the function, so I tried 44000 instead (knowing it is incorrect). Then I just get a z array of zeroes.

Questions: Most of the time sample rate is not a perfect multiple of the symbol rate. Is this really a requirement of Octave?  If so, how do I "stretch" or "resample" my data at 44000 instead of 44100, which is what Audacity really did?

But even then, the function is returning all zeroes.  Any ideas?